# error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'localPosition'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

H, I'm going to develop a drag and drop game with unity but this error appears, how to fix this error, please!

this is the full error
( error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'localPosition' and no accessible extension method 'localPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

[image: this is the full error]

this is my code in the C# script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject correctForm; 
    
    private bool moving; // to check if it is moving or not 
    private float startPosX; 
    private float startPosY; 


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(moving){
            Vector3 mousePos; 
            mousePos= Input.mousePosition; 
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos); 

            this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, this.gameObject.localPosition.z);
        }
        
    }


    public void OnMouseUp(){

        moving = false; 

    } 


    public void OnMouseDown(){

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos; 
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos); 

            startPosX = mousePos.x - this.transform.localPosition.x;
            startPosY = mousePos.y - this.transform.localPosition.y; 

            moving = true; 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't ... do you mean `this.gameObject.transform.localPosition.z` ? Voting to close this as typo-based

Answer (score 1):

In the update function, in last parameter of last line, you typed **this.gameObject.localPosition.z**. [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) has no field named **localPosition**. You should fix it by **this.gameObject.transform.localPosition.z**. In conclusion, your Update should looks like this:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(moving){
        Vector3 mousePos; 
        mousePos= Input.mousePosition; 
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos); 

        this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, this.gameObject.transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    
}
```